# "unexpected indent" error when using notepad++ for creating django function

Tags: python, django, notepad++, indentation

I am following [this book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/) to learn django using notepad++, something interesting happens, when I type the function using notepad++ for the following script:

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

It gives me an error like this:

```
IndentationError at /time/

('unexpected indent', ('M:\\DjangoStack\\projects\\beta_01\\..\\beta_01\\hello_world\\views.py', 12, 1, '\thtml = "<html>"\n'))
```

But when I paste it directly from the book, it is OK. I wonder why, should I do some settings in notepad++? Thanks.

#### update 01

I use `4 space bars` to create the indent in notepad++, I tried `1 tab` and seems the problem is fixed

Comment: Does your Notepad++ use tabs for indentation? There appears to be some inconsistency between spaces and tabs in this particular function when you typed it in Notepad++.

Comment: Can you confirm that there are no tabs? Run this through search-and-replace (match control sequences): replace `\t` with `[single space]`.

Answer (score 28):

Tell Notepad++ to show you all characters: go View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters. This will show tabs as `→` and spaces as `∙`. Replace tabs with spaces where necessary to normalize the indentation.

Answer (score 24):

Settings->Preferences->Language Menu/Tab Settings->"Replace by space"

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ it is a checkbox here:

- Settings>Preferences>

[image]